# Kentico: Feature 'MVTesting' is not available in the Kentico edition you are using. See event log for more details

Tags: kentico

Just created a folder in Pages, tried to sync it, got an error:
Feature 'MVTesting' is not available in the Kentico edition you are using. See event log for more details.

What am I doing wrong?

Kentico v12.0

Comment: I'm just guessing, but perhaps there are more details in the event log?

Comment: Not really, this is pretty much it.

Comment: Exception type: System.Net.WebException

Comment: Stack trace:
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.Server.SyncServerWse.ProcessSynchronizationTaskData(String stagingTaskData)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.Server.SyncServerWse.ProcessSynchronizationTaskData(IStagingTaskData stagingTaskData)
at CMS.Synchronization.WSE3.SyncClient.RunTask(StagingTaskInfo taskObj)

Comment: Means nothing to me :)

Comment: I don't know in this specific case, but as a general rule, when asking a debugging question, it's best to include _all_ the details that might be relevant, even if they don't mean anything to you. Somebody might be able to help you understand them, and thus your problem, but they can't do that with information you don't pass on. Even the information that there _weren't_ more details in the log improves the question. On a technical note, you should [edit] the question itself to include those details, as this comment area is intended for short messages which can be deleted later.

Answer (score 1):

First off, never run a website on a vanilla version of Kentico. Run the hotfix utility and apply the latest hotfix.

Second, are you using Portal Engine it MVC?

Thirdly, I'd you're using a Kentico starter site like Dancing Goat, you may come across this error because you have an invalid license key which does not support the MVT features which are part of the EMS license.

Lastly, [Google the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=Feature%20%27MVTesting%27%20is%20not%20available%20in%20the%20Kentico%20edition%20you%20are%20using.&oq=Feature%20%27MVTesting%27%20is%20not%20available%20in%20the%20Kentico%20edition%20you%20are%20using.&aqs=chrome..69i57.2103j0j7&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) and you'll find several other suggestions which are all part of the same family of Kentico licensing issues.

Comment: Just to add to what you said about applying hotfixes - man can check the already known and fixed bugs here: https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes

Comment: Using Portal Engine. Custom built site - no Dancing Goat or any other Kentico starter site.

Comment: We never had EMS license, not sure why this error is popping up now, it was fine before, I was able to sync folders or anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that there is the default "Empty" page template which was using some of the default MVT testing enabled on the sample web sites or maybe it is a leftover form the trial period or from some sample site template.

One option is to check the **OM_MVTCombination** database table and clear it out if there are any data.

Another option is to check the pages what template they are using, after you find out what template is used you could do the following:

1. Delete all the problematic tasks from the list in Staging application.
2. Delete given page template(s).
3. Create new page template(s) and assign it to these pages.
4. Sync it.

This would ensure there is no reference to some MVT testing. You can try it with one particular page and page template to be sure it works and then perform this for all problematic pages and page templates.

Comment: This did help! Created a new page template from scratch that is identical to the previous one - and the new one synced fine. Strange, but it worked so all is good.